# Threads vs Timer vs Service

Tags: c#, .net

I was reading this blog [Easy Background Tasks](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/) about the badge system of some page called stackoverflow :P, so, in a comment says that they ended with a service that perform the task, but for example:

User performs action in time T1
This action depends of X number of users
After time T2, you need to execute some db query and notify user(email or whatever)

I say this because of the real time experience, so the question here is, if you use threads, lets say you have 1000 users that perform actions, you will have 1000 waiting threads, so in some time, there will be reciclyng, or if the server shutsdown for some reason, you will lose all this tasks. Using a timer will end in the same situation

If you use a service you will lose the real time experience, for example in an online game.

So, how to deal with this kind of stuff?

Comment: You use a "background task" only when the timing is not critical.  Certainly the case for SO badges, nobody will complain when the badge gets awarded a minute late.  If "real time" is important to you then don't consider a background task.  And **never** write code that creates a thousand waiting threads.

Comment: Well i wont complain if badges are awarded in the next hour for example. So, threads are not an option here, because I would need to create thousand of them, so what do you suggest?, A service that check for this everty hour for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be careful when using threads and signaling.
The solution depends to the details of the scenario, but one of the scalable solutions is **polling**.

Based on your scenario, signaling between threads is not efficient as there's always a limited number of available threads in the threadpool. However, if you know the maximum number of users who will hold a thread ( depending on the game design ) , you can use signaling using WaitHandles ( AutoResetEvent and/or ManualResetEvent) to signal between threads. But make sure that you have increased the number of available threads in the pool in the Application_Start event handler of the Global.asax

```
            int availableThreads;

            int availablePorts;

            ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out availableThreads, out availablePorts);

            ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(availableThreads, availablePorts);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: A thead pool sounds like a really good option, but i need to create N threads from each user, so my number of threads will be the sum of the threads per user. So, what do you think, should I still use a thread pool?

Comment: I would suggest you to consider adding a timer, and a hashtable ( to collect user specific data ) to each of your users. There's always a limitation  in using threads. The maximum number of available threads can be calculated by this formula: Max_Available_Threads=250*[No_CPU_CORE], so if you're running on a 12 core cpu machine you will have up to 3,000 available threads. So based on this number, using threads is not suitable for high number of users in a game.